# Changing specific row in listview cause another row to mirror the change

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Hey guys I am new to android and trying to wrap my head around this bug I have. So I have a basic listview with 2 buttons, one to increment and another to decrement a textview in that row. When I click either button, the desired textview (row 0) changes but so does another row which is not even onscreen (row 5).

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Item item = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_name);
    ImageView ivItemPicture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_item_pic);
    final TextView tvAmount = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_amount);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvItem.setText(item.getName());
    ivItemPicture.setImageResource(item.getImageResId());

    //incremt textview
    ImageButton ibtnPlus = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_plus);
    ibtnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(tvAmount.getText().toString());
            if(value >= 0){
                value = value + 1;
                tvAmount.setText(Integer.toString(value));

            }
        }
    });
    //decrement textview
    ImageButton ibtnMinus = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_btn_minus);
    ibtnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt((tvAmount.getText().toString()));

            if (value > 0){
                value = value - 1;
                tvAmount.setText(Integer.toString(value));
            }
        }
    });

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Use `ArrayList` to hold count. And increment that specific index's count `onClick() event`. And use that list's count to set text of `tvAmount`. Feel free to ask if you have more doubts regarding this. I would be happy to help.

Comment: like Patel said, you need to update the status of count in list. And use the list item to set data in getView.

Comment: @bionio the reason for this is you depend on tvAmount this view will be recycled whenever you scroll and it'll be used again. The view won't create again it just will be reused. So keep the value which you want to show on the textview in some container as other's said i ArrayList or Anyway u have **Item** model keep a field for amount and pick it from that item and set

Comment: Wow, i appreciate the quick response. Both responses worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are implementing your adapter is wrong. Your code is calling findViewById() for each item you are scrolling of ListView, which is slowing down performance. Beside that to hold the components view we usually use the **view holder** design pattern.

In your **Adapter** class make a **ViewHolder** class according to your specific requirements:

```
static class ViewHolder {
  TextView tvItem;
  TextView tvAmount;
  ImageView ivItemPicture;
}
```

Then populate the **ViewHolder** and save it inside the layout:

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
holder. ivItemPicture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_item_pic);
holder. tvAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_amount);
holder. tvItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_lv_name);
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Search view holder for more information and this should solve your problem.